# Un-Merge a List

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

## Introduction

Most of you are familiar with the [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm for sorting a list of numbers.
As part of the algorithm, one writes a helper function called `merge` that combines two sorted lists into one sorted list.
In Python-like pseudocode, the function usually looks something like this:

```
function merge(A, B):
  C = []
  while A is not empty or B is not empty:
    if A is empty:
      C.append(B.pop())
    else if B is empty or A[0] ≤ B[0]:
      C.append(A.pop())
    else:
      C.append(B.pop())
  return C
```

The idea is to keep popping the smaller of the first elements of `A` and `B` until both lists are empty, and collect the results into `C`.
If `A` and `B` are both sorted, then so is `C`.

Conversely, if `C` is a sorted list, and we split it into any two subsequences `A` and `B`, then `A` and `B` are also sorted and `merge(A, B) == C`.
Interestingly, this does not necessarily hold if `C` is not sorted, which brings us to this challenge.

## Input

Your input is a permutation of the first `2*n` nonnegative integers `[0, 1, 2, ..., 2*n-1]` for some `n > 0`, given as a list `C`.

## Output

Your output shall be a truthy value if there exist two lists `A` and `B` of length `n` such that `C == merge(A, B)`, and a falsy value otherwise.
Since the input contains no duplicates, you don't have to worry about how ties are broken in the `merge` function.

## Rules and Bonuses

You can write either a function or a full program.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

Note that you are not required to compute the lists `A` and `B` in the "yes" instances.
However, if you actually output the lists, you receive a **bonus of -20%**.
To claim this bonus, you must output only one pair of lists, not all possibilities.
To make this bonus easier to claim in strongly typed languages, it is allowed to output a pair of empty lists in the "no" instances.

Brute forcing is not forbidden, but there is a **bonus of -10%** for computing all of the last four test cases in under 1 second total.

## Test Cases

Only one possible output is given in the "yes" instances.

```
[1,0] -> False
[0,1] -> [0] [1]
[3,2,1,0] -> False
[0,3,2,1] -> False
[0,1,2,3] -> [0,1] [2,3]
[1,4,0,3,2,5] -> False
[4,2,0,5,1,3] -> [4,2,0] [5,1,3]
[3,4,1,2,5,0] -> [4,1,2] [3,5,0]
[6,2,9,3,0,7,5,1,8,4] -> False
[5,7,2,9,6,8,3,4,1,0] -> False
[5,6,0,7,8,1,3,9,2,4] -> [6,0,8,1,3] [5,7,9,2,4]
[5,3,7,0,2,9,1,6,4,8] -> [5,3,7,0,2] [9,1,6,4,8]
[0,6,4,8,7,5,2,3,9,1] -> [8,7,5,2,3] [0,6,4,9,1]
[9,6,10,15,12,13,1,3,8,19,0,16,5,7,17,2,4,11,18,14] -> False
[14,8,12,0,5,4,16,9,17,7,11,1,2,10,18,19,13,15,6,3] -> False
[4,11,5,6,9,14,17,1,3,15,10,12,7,8,0,18,19,2,13,16] -> [4,17,1,3,15,10,12,7,8,0] [11,5,6,9,14,18,19,2,13,16]
[9,4,2,14,7,13,1,16,12,11,3,8,6,15,17,19,0,10,18,5] -> [9,4,2,16,12,11,3,8,6,15] [14,7,13,1,17,19,0,10,18,5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 39 * 0.9 * 0.8 = 28.08

```
#aY->QxQeS-QsY&YsY)KfqylTlQmsdty_Y%tlKK
```

This program clams all two bonuses. It prints a pair of lists, if un-merging is possible, else an empty list, which is a falsy value in Pyth (and Python).

```
Input:  [5,3,7,0,2,9,1,6,4,8]
Output: ([9, 1, 6, 4, 8], [5, 3, 7, 0, 2])
Input:  [5,7,2,9,6,8,3,4,1,0]
Output: [] (falsy value)
```

You can test it [online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23aY-%3EQxQeS-QsY%26YsY)KfqylTlQmsdty_Y%25tlKK&input=%5B5%2C3%2C7%2C0%2C2%2C9%2C1%2C6%2C4%2C8%5D&debug=0), but it may be a bit slower than the offline version. The offline version solves each of the test cases in <0.15 seconds on my laptop.

Probably (one of) the first time, a Pyth solution uses actively **Exceptions** (it saved at least 1 char). It uses the same idea as Peter Taylor's solution.

```
                         preinitialisations: Q = input(), Y = []
#                 )     while 1: (infinite loop)
        eS-QsY             finds the biggest, not previous used, number
      xQ                   finds the index
    >Q                     all elements from ... to end
   -          &YsY         but remove all used elements
 aY                        append the resulting list to Y

When all numbers are used, finding the biggest number fails, 
throws an exception and the while loop ends.  
This converts [5,3,7,0,2,9,1,6,4,8] to [[9, 1, 6, 4, 8], [7, 0, 2], [5, 3]]

        msdty_Y  combine the lists each for every possible subset of Y (except the empty subset)
 fqylTlQ         and filter them for lists T with 2*len(T) == len(Q)
K                and store them in K

%tlKK        print K[::len(K)-1] (prints first and last if K, else empty list)
```

## Pyth, 30 * 0.9 = 27.0

I haven't really tried solving it without printing the resulting lists. But here's a quick solution based on the code above.

```
#aY->QxQeS-QsY&YsY)fqylsTlQtyY
```

I basically only removed the print statement. The output is quite ugly though.

```
Input:  [0,1,2,3]
Output: [[[3], [2]], [[3], [1]], [[2], [1]], [[3], [0]], [[2], [0]], [[1], [0]]] (truthy value)
Input:  [5,7,2,9,6,8,3,4,1,0]
Output: [] (falsy value)
```

Try it [online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23aY-%3EQxQeS-QsY%26YsY)fqylsTlQtyY&input=%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%5D&debug=0).

Comment: You may find that rather than printing `(K[0], Q-K[0])` you can print `(K[0], K[-1])`. I don't know whether that would give a saving, though.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks, saved 2 chars.

Comment: @PeterTaylor and even 2 more chars, if I print `K[::len(K)-1]`.

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript (35 * 0.9 = 31.5)

```
{.$-1>/~,)\.}do;]1,\{{1$+}+%}/)2/&,
```

The [online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=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%3D) is quite slow: on my computer, it runs all of the tests in under 0.04 seconds, so I claim the 10% reduction.

#### Explanation

> The suffix of C which starts with the largest number in C must come from the same list. Then this reasoning can be applied to (C - suffix), so that the problem reduces to subset sum.

Answer (score 2):

## APL, <strike>62</strike> <strike>50</strike> 44 * 90% = 39.6

```
{(l÷2)⌷↑(⊢∨⌽)/(2-/(1,⍨⍵≥⌈\⍵)/⍳l+1),⊂l=⍳l←⍴⍵}
```

[Try it here.](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%28l%F72%29%u2337%u2191%28%u22A2%u2228%u233D%29/%282-/%281%2C%u2368%u2375%u2265%u2308%5C%u2375%29/%u2373l+1%29%2C%u2282l%3D%u2373l%u2190%u2374%u2375%7D9%204%202%2014%207%2013%201%2016%2012%2011%203%208%206%2015%2017%2019%200%2010%2018%205&run)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 103 bytes * 0.9 * 0.8

```javascript
f=(x,u,a=[],b=[],y=[...x],c=y.pop())=>b[0]<a[0]?0:1/c?f(y,~-u,[c,...a],b)||f(y,~u,[c,...b],a):u?0:[a,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLNboJAEL7zFNxcmhF3BRFt0Zsv0OOGNisuxoaKVWlqYvrqdmYWrdpyIOz3Nz/Lm/k0u2K72uy763phT6cyE1/QgMl0DnN6HTIdhuFXDkV2CDf1RgRBNplrmT8ZfE3lWPWKaSkO8N1tQBeAYoPW4Hhk8IzNczDBuEG9NjDPT4/e1n40q60VnXLXCcKtNYvZqrLPh3UhJHSafZkyvKlMYUXvJXyY@r33Jbxmk6Je7@rKhlW9FKWwn6YSrwE@J61A5n534s9MtbOelqD4iI36WuWejqAPfzQM3tkQilorcZqOHsbH4PSDa32MgIQBuloPA@hyEJWNOXLQltZ8REHEkKcTJEcYLGHIOSnE1wUGCJMgQcJlyVs6YWdK5VDWb92a4NS1xRmOIkOEJ8mZCs0xpM5wIdDwS9FG@Iu763ONdrEXKPdbEVGepl4Vrg6HweVG3Bh2MsJslQD1omgkHEWBQuJmXEWllNtpTPoRqYespbuSbBlxLs0e3V4GyghFPiYflaY@JEXSks5211hyuZH/pPTfXMfdGGlMumokhm5I7JXmddMmnDVsp@aq7rc52@7FVOw36s7oeT8)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 105 bytes * 0.9 * 0.8

```javascript
f=(x,u=0,a=[],b=[],y=[...x],c=y.pop())=>b[0]<a[0]?0:1/c?f(y,u-1,[c,...a],b)||f(y,~u,[c,...b],a):u?0:[a,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLNboJAEL7zFNxcmhF3BRFt0Zsv0OOGNitdGhsqVsVoYvrqdmYWrdpyIOz3Nz/Lh9mZTbFerLbdZf1mT6cyE3toMgkm0znM6XXIdBiG@xyK7BCu6pUIgmwy1zJ/MviayrHqFdNSHKDpKtAFoNigNTgeCfxuWmyegwnGDeq1gXl@evTW9qtZrK3olJtOEK6teZstKvt8WBZCQqfZlinDq8oUVvRewoep3/t8h9dsUtTLTV3ZsKrfRSnszlTiNcDnpBXI3O9O/JmpNtbTEhQfsVFfq9zTEfThj4bBOxtCUWslTtPRw/gYnH5wrY8RkDBAV@thAF0OorIxRw7a0pqPKIgY8nSC5AiDJQw5J4X4usAAYRIkSLgseUsn7EypHMr6rVsTnLq2OMNRZIjwJDlToTmG1BkuBBp@KdoIf3F3fa7RLvYC5X4rIsrT1KvC1eEwuNyIG8NORpitEqBeFI2EoyhQSNyMq6iUcjuNST8i9ZC1dFeSLSPOpdmj28tAGaHIx@Sj0tSHpEha0tnuGksuN/KflP6b67gbI41JV43E0A2JvdK8btqEs4bt1FzV/TZn272Yiv1G3Rk97wc)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 115 bytes * 0.9 * 0.8

```javascript
f=(x,u=0,a=[],b=[],y=[...x],c=y.pop())=>1/c?!(b[0]<c)&&f(y,u-1,[c,...a],b)||!(a[0]<c)&&f(y,~u,[c,...b],a):u?0:[a,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJLb4JAEL7zK@ilLs2Iu4KIbdFb/0CPG2pWujQ2VKyKqUnTv25nZvHZciDs95rH8m62Zl2s5stNd1G/2v2@zMQXNJkEk@kcZvTaZToMw68cimwXLuulCIJsrHrF5EbMtMwfi@D2thQ7aLoKdAGoNegMvr9vhDnnf5qWnuVggvtmIu@1gVm@f/BW9rOZr6zolOtOEK6seX2aV/Z5tyiEhE6zKVOGl5UprOi9hHcTv/fxBtNsXNSLdV3ZsKrfRCns1lRiGuCz1wpk7nfH/pOp1tbTEhQfsSNfq9zTEfThj4bBKxtCUWslTtPRw/gYnH5wro8RkDBAV@thAF0OorIxRw7a0pqPKIgY8nSC5AiDJQw5J4X4vMAAYRIkSLgseUkn7EypHMr6rVsTnLq2OMNRZIjwJDlToTmG1BmOBBpOFG2Ev7i7PtdoF3uEcr8VEeVp6lXh6nAYXG7EjWEnI8xWCVAvikbCURQoJC7GVVRKuZ3GpB@ReshauivJlhHn0uzR5WWgjFDkY/JRaepDUiQt6WB3jSXHG/lPSv/NedyFkcakq0Zi6IbEXmleN23CWcN2aq7qfpuD7VpMxU5RV0bP@wU)